# Vuex store initiated in mainjs but is undefined in App.vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Axios from "axios";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
})

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

when I try to use $store in `App.vue` it is undefined:

```
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('logout') // this.$store is undefined
  }
```

store.js:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    logout({commit}) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('logout')
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        delete Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
        resolve()
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Is it because it is not initiated in App.vue, **because I can use at other vue components**.

Comment: show your action logout method that u have in your store

Comment: Updated my question on store.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't imported Vuex in Main.JS:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
```

Learn more about installing Vuex [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html)
EDIT: Legit everyone just stole my answer...

Answer (score 3):

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    // Options
});
```

And just put to the Vue Instance.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install Vuex using `npm install vuex --save`

Then, import it into your `store.js`.

[image]

To understand **WHEN**, **WHY** and **HOW** to use Vuex, refer this URL https://dev.to/napoleon039/when-why-and-how-to-use-vuex-9fl